# Pandas equivelt of pyspark reduce and add?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the following where Day_1, Day_2, Day_3 are the number of impressions in the past 3 days.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Day_1': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'Day_2': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'Day_3': [1, 1, 0, 0],
                  index=['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4'])
df
      Day_1 Day_2 Day_3 
user1   2    2      1   
user2   4    0      1   
user3   8    0      0   
user4   0    0      0
```

Now, I need to check if a user had any impression in the past `n` days. For example, if `num_days = 2`, I need to add a new column, `impression`, where it gets 1 if sum Day_1 and Day_2 is greater than zero, and `0` otherwise. Here is what I expect to see:

```
      Day_1 Day_2 Day_3 impression
user1   2    2      1   1
user2   4    0      1   1
user3   8    0      0   1
user4   0    0      0   0
```

It is a straightforward process in `pyspark` and I use something like this:

```
imp_cols = ['Day_'+str(i) for i in range(1, num_days+1)]
df = df.withColumn("impression",reduce(add, [F.col(x) for x in imp_cols]))
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).

Try this :

```
df["impression"] = np.where(df.sum(axis=1).gt(0), 1, 0)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
​
       Day_1  Day_2  Day_3  impression
user1      2      2      1           1
user2      4      0      1           1
user3      8      0      0           1
user4      0      0      0           0
```

If you want to select a specific columns/days, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) :

```
num_days = 2
l = list(range(1, num_days+1))
pat= "|".join([str(x) for x in l])

sub_df = df.filter(regex="Day_[{}]".format(pat))

df["impression"] = np.where(sub_df.sum(axis=1).gt(0), 1, 0)
```